# Is there a faster method for iterating over a very big 2D numpy array than using np.where?

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-computing, gdal

i have a huge 2D numpy array filled with integer values. I collect them from a *.tif-image* via gdal.GetRasterBand().
The pixel values of the image represent unique cluster-identification numbers. So all pixels inside one cluster have the same value.
In my script i want to check if the clusters have more pixels than a specific threshold. If the clustersize is bigger than the threshold I want to keep the cluster and give them a pixel value 1. If a cluster has less pixel then the threshold, all pixels of this cluster should get the value 0.

My code so far works, but is very very slow. And because i want to vary the threshold, it takes like forever.
I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
# Import GeoTIFF via GDAL and convert to NumpyArray
data = gdal.Open(image)
raster = data.GetRasterBand(1)
raster = raster.ReadAsArray()

# Different thresholds for iteration
thresh = [0,10,25,50,100,1000,2000]

for threshold in thresh:
        clusteredRaster = np.array(raster.copy(), dtype = int)

        for clump in np.unique(clusteredRaster): # Unique ids of the clusters in image

            if clusteredRaster[np.where(clusteredRaster == clump)].size >= threshold: 
                clusteredRaster[np.where(clusteredRaster == clump)] = int(1)

            else:
                clusteredRaster[np.where(clusteredRaster == clump)] = int(0)
'''

[ClusterImage][1]

In the image you can see the cluster image. Each color stands vor a specific clusternumber. I want to delete the small ones (under a specific size) and just keep the big ones.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/miEKg.png
```

Comment: Can `np.unique(clusteredRaster)` be moved out of the `threshold` loop?

Comment: unfortunately not, because i use different images and the unique values get different with every image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a easy solution based on your helpful answers!
The idea is to find the unique values and cluster sizes per threshold and instant fill in correct values, thus avoid a loop.
It reduces the iteration time from initially 142 seconds per iteration to 0.52 seconds and reproduces the same results.

```
data = gdal.Open(image)
raster = data.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

thresh = [0, 10, 25, 50, 100, 1000, 2000]   
for threshold in thresh:
    # Create new 0-raster with same dimensions as input raster
    clusteredRaster = np.zeros(raster.shape, dtype = uint8)
    
    # Get unique cluster IDs and count the size of the occurence
    clumps, counts = np.unique(raster, return_counts=True)

    # Get only the clumps which are bigger than the threshold
    biggerClumps = clumps[counts >= threshold]

    # fill in ones for the relevant cluster IDs
    clusteredRaster[np.isin(raster,biggerClumps)] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of modifications that can be done to improve performance,

```py
clusteredRaster = np.array(raster.copy(), dtype = int)
```

can be replaced with

```py
clusteredRaster = raster.astype(int)
```

which this is essentially both a copy and a casting operator so this operation is faster.

now for

```py
clusteredRaster[np.where(clusteredRaster == clump)] = int(1)
```

you don't need to call np.where, this will work faster

```py
clusteredRaster[clusteredRaster == clump] = int(1)
```

also done for this part

```py
clusteredRaster[np.where(clusteredRaster == clump)].size
```

you can also remove the evaluation of clusteredRaster==clump twice as follow:

```py
for clump in np.unique(clusteredRaster): # Unique ids of the clusters in image
    indicies = clusteredRaster==clump

    if clusteredRaster[indicies].size >= threshold: 
        clusteredRaster[indicies] = int(1)

    else:
        clusteredRaster[indicies] = int(0)
```

i think your function will now work twice as fast, however if you want to run faster, you have to use smaller datatypes like np.uint8 instead of plain int, provided your image is encoded in RGB and can be represented by 8 bit ints (or maybe np.uint16 if 8 bits is too low ?)
this is as fast as it can get from python side.

there are faster methods like using C modules with openmp to multithread your work across multiple cores, this can easily be done with something like [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) or [cython](https://cython.org/) without having to worry about writing C code, but there's a lot of reading to do if you want to achieve the fastest performance ever, like which threading backend to use (TBB vs openmp) and some os and device dependent capabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! My iteration time gets down from 216 seconds to 46 seconds, which already helps a lot! 
Unfortunately i need at least uint32 because my unique values get that high...
However i will try to read into numba or cython. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [changes suggested by Ahmed Mohamed AEK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70337404) you can also take the calculation of unique values, indices, and counts outside of the for loops. Plus you don't need to copy `raster` each time - you can make an array of `np.uint8`s.

This gives the same results as your original implementation:

```
data = gdal.Open(image)
raster = data.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

# Different thresholds for iteration
thresh = [0, 10, 25, 50, 100, 1000, 2000]

# determine the unique clumps and their frequencies outside of the for loops
clumps, counts = np.unique(raster, return_counts=True)

# only determine the indices once, rather than for each threshold
indices = np.asarray([raster==clump for clump in clumps])

for threshold in thresh:
    
    clustered_raster = np.zeros_like(raster, dtype=np.uint8)

    for clump_indices, clump_counts in zip(indices, counts):
    
        clustered_raster[clump_indices] = clump_counts >= threshold
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Based on your idea I managed to completely avoid a new for loop which drastically decreases time!